# how to use two properties with ngModel?

Tags: html, angular

in a form in angular 2 I filled ngModel with properties of a class. But I have 2 extra properties for example when user fill email input I want two properties get this value(email and username) and when fill password input two properties get this value(password and confirmPassword).
What is the syntax of it?I tried this but it sends error:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="createuser.pasword;createuser.confirmPassword" name="password" type="password" minlength="6" required>
```

createuser is object of CreateUser:

```
export  class CreateUser {
mail: string;
UserName: string;
password: string;
confirmPassword: string;}
```

thanks a lot for your helping in a simple way.

Comment: Not sure but I think this is not supported.

Comment: If you intend to use email as username, just leave out the username field and set it in your backend appropriately. As for the password, if you want to set password and confirmpassword with one input field, your confirmpassword field makes no sense to even be there. Use two separate fields.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that Angular support binding `ngModel` to two properties. But accomplishing your task is possible by combining `ngModel` and `(event)` like below:

- bind the mail property via `[(ngModel)]`.
- then bind the username to mail by using an `input` event listen.

component.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mail" (input)="setUserName($event)">
<p>
  mail {{mail}}
</p>

<p>
  username {{UserName}}
</p>
```

component.ts

```
export class CreateUser{
  mail: string;
  UserName: string;
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;

  constructor() { }

  setUserName(event) {
    this.UserName = event.target.value;
    // or 
    // this.UserName = this.mail;
  }
}
```

Although this works properly, I don't understand the necessity to use it. As it's said in the comments above you can leave a field empty then handle it properly in the backend.

Comment: Thank you Abdelaziz, yes you are right but I need to do this in front.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a lot I found I can do like this in component of ts:

```
this.createuser.mail=this.createuser.UserName;
this.createuser.confirmPassword=this.createuser.pasword;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible. This, for example, works very nice, but I'm not sure is it OK to handle it this way:  `[(ngModel)]="address.city + ' ' + address.zipCode"`

Comment: no, not work and really the solucion is simply "split" the ngmodel:`<input [ngModel]="createuser.pasword" (ngModelChange)="createuser.confirmPassword=$event;createuser.pasword=$event">`

Comment: @Eliseo I've test it in the real app we are working on before I wrote this, and I get the results as expected.

Comment: `[ngModel]` works, but it's not possible two ways binding . If you try your code give an error